# 'ExitActionIteration' possible on the 'first level' action?

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I have a complex testing framework which works with nested action calls. In some cases (depends on the testdata) I need to skip the current `ActionIteration` in the `top-level-action`. 
The `top-level-action` is located in the executing testscript and its localsheet contains the testdata.

Is there any possibility to send the `ExitActionIteration` command from a called `sub-action` to the `top-level-action`?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use a boolean variable which will be set in the sub-action at the Exit condition. This variable will then be read by the top-level-action and can accordingly exit its iteration

Comment: We are now using an environment variable and a 'Skrip-Iteration-Function' (called ExitTestcaseActionIteration) that checks the state of the environment variable and do the 'ExitActionIteration' if necessary.
Nevertheless that is only a workaround and shows the limits of the QTP-Action-Structure/Concept.